# How to search string over multiple fields in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have to  search "oil" over fields "BrandName","Desc" &"cat"

And in BrandName filed I have data "lucasoil product" data  as oil is present in this I want this also to be get hit

I am using

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "must" : {
      "query_string" : {
        "query" : "oil",
        "fields" : [ "BrandName", "Cat","Desc" ],
        "default_operator" : "and"
      }
    }
  }
```

But this not giving me the exact results, how to sort this out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query

```
{
  "query" :{
     "bool" : {
        "must" : {
          "query_string" : {
            "query" : "oil",
            "fields" : [ "input", "output"],
            "default_operator" : "and"
          }
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Check your mapping also once. It will look like this

```
{
    "test":
    {
        "properties":
        {
            "BrandName":
            {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "Cat":
            {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "Desc":
            {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Vinod can you Please share me the java Code ,i mean how query comes at the top of the elastic search query instead of bool

Comment: You have to frame that query in java or keep it in properties file and read this query from java class.